# <DataGrid> property "onCellEditCommit" doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, edit

I'm using the `DataGrid` component of `Material-UI` for **displaying a list of items**.

I want to **make each** **cell** in every row **editable** and then **change the corresponding item of that row**.

for that purpose, I'm using the `onCellEditCommit` property provided on the `DataGrid` component.
But, when I actually change a value of a cell, **my event handler doesn't invoke**.

I use the following code:

```js
 export default function TargetsView(props) {
      const [items] = useContext(TargetsContext);
      const onItemsEnabled = props.onItemsEnabled;

      return (
        <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
          <DataGrid
            disableSelectionOnClick
            onCellEditCommit={(params) => {
              console.log("test");
            }}
            onSelectionModelChange={
              onItemsEnabled
                ? (selectedRows) => {
                    const targetInformation = [];
                    for (let selectedRow of selectedRows)
                      targetInformation.push(items[selectedRow - 1]);
                      onItemsEnabled(targetInformation);
                  }
                : null
            }
            rows={items}
            columns={columns}
            checkboxSelection
            experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OnCellEditCommit is part of the legacy editing api: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing-legacy/#events

Your code should not contain the line:
`experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true}}`

```js
 export default function TargetsView(props) {
      const [items] = useContext(TargetsContext);
      const onItemsEnabled = props.onItemsEnabled;

      return (
        <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
          <DataGrid
            disableSelectionOnClick
            onCellEditCommit={(params) => {
              console.log("test");
            }}
            onSelectionModelChange={
              onItemsEnabled
                ? (selectedRows) => {
                    const targetInformation = [];
                    for (let selectedRow of selectedRows)
                      targetInformation.push(items[selectedRow - 1]);
                      onItemsEnabled(targetInformation);
                  }
                : null
            }
            rows={items}
            columns={columns}
            checkboxSelection
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. It worked for me.

Comment: What is the equivalent to `onCellEditCommit` in the new editing api then?

Comment: Equivalent to `onCellEditCommit` in the new API is `processRowUpdate`. More info [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#persistence).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been outdated. Try using *processRowUpdate*. This returns the entire row, with the updated value.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4568#issuecomment-1102611055